# Is it a good practice to add additional information in order to not make more calls?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Let's say that the users can add posts on a public board.

Should the post objects contain not only the `uid` of the user that created the post and the actual post, but also the additional information that would be displayed in the UI to other users such as the poster's first name, last name etc.?

If this information would not be included, there would be needed one more call to retrieve them.

I think it is problematic when an user decides to change his/her name for example, because that would mean to update all the posts created by the respective user.

What is your opinion? Thanks.

Edit:

To show an example, which would be better between the two versions of `post`:

```
"post_id": {
    "firstName": "Adam",
    "lastName": "Smith",
    "byUser": "uid",
    "message": "message1"
}
```

or

```
"post_id": {
    "byUser": "uid",
    "message": "message1"
}
```

where

```
 "user_uid": {
        "firstName": "Adam",
        "lastName": "Smith"
    }
```

Comment: @PeterHaddad Hi! Yes, but it didn't really answer my question. I am wondering about performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the name next to the user's post then use this:

```
 "post_id": {
 "name": "Adam Smith",
"byUser": "uid",
"message": "message1"
}
```

This way when retrieving a list of posts, you do only one call. Also add a `users` node in the database that will contain the list of users:

```
 "users" :{
      "name": "Adam Smith", 
       "email": "email@gmail.com"
    }
```

This way when a user wants to update his name, it will be updated in the list of `users` and update it also in the `post_id`. Thus when retrieving the posts of a user in a Home Activity(that contains all posts) you will also get the updated name.

this might help: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/04/denormalizing-your-data-is-normal.html

Comment: But what if there are many posts? That would take time server side.

Comment: Which one would take time?  And it really depends on thr query,  if you iterate through the whole node or if you just go to one node

Comment: It’s like you are searching through all the comments on YouTube and changing the name of the poster’s in the respective nodes. Wouldn’t that be pretty inefficient?

Comment: No, the reason I wrote the name with the post. Since when you want to retrieve the posts and the name, if they are in different nodes then you have to do a two queries which will take more time than just doing one query. Regarding changing the name, the user will have an update profile page where he changes his name. Then when he is going to a page where he commented, he will get his new name there since the data is just being retrieved from the database anw

Comment: @TomaRadu-Petrescu to elaborate, regarding changing the name. Usually the user will change his name on his own in a page called "Update profile". After he saves his changes then `name` under post_id and under `users` will be updated. Then(for example) if that user went to a youtube page, in that page you will be retrieving the data under `post_id` which will contain the new name of that user. So no it wont be changing the name while checking the comments, when you enter the page->data is retrieved from post_id-> it will already contain the name if updated or not also!

Comment: That contradicts your initial answer. It means that the name is not needed in the post structure.

Comment: It is needed to only do one query when retrieving the post with the name. If it is not with it then you need to do two queries

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165663/discussion-between-peter-haddad-and-toma-radu-petrescu).